# analytic geometry question involving perpendicular vectors

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Determine the parametrics equations of the straight line that passes by $A(-1,4,5)$ and is perpendicular to $r:P=(-2,1,1)+t(1,-1,1)$.

Someone can solve this? I'm trying for more than a hour and I'm not having success...

Comment: Do you mean passes through (-1,4,5).  I will give a hint.    A vector passing through A and touching the line has the form $v=P-A$, so that $v=(-1+t, -3-t, -4+t).$  The direction vector for the line is $u=(1,-1,1).$  You can get the direction vector the is perpendicular by looking at the dot product $u \cdot v.$

Comment: Thanks, excuse my english, I'll try what you said.

Comment: I keep getting $v=(-1/3,-11/3,-10/3)$ and the answer given is $v=(-1,-11,10)$. Is the textbook wrong or what?

Comment: You are free to scale a direction vector by any non-zero number.   Your vector is 1/3 the textbook value.  So you are both right.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks matt.